# how to declare a variable inside a flatList renderItem?

Tags: react-native, momentjs, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to fetch the date and format it using moment , the solution i found is to store the date in a variable , and i've been having a problem with that followed this  [awnser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47120286/unexpected-token-when-trying-to-declare-a-variable-inside-flatlist-in-react-nati) since i hade the same problem . although i managed to get rid of the unexpected token error but i got my self in another one . MY FLAT LIST IS NOT SHOWING ANYMORE.
 here is my code :

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
import {View,StyleSheet,FlatList,ListView} from "react-native";
import {Container, Header, Left, Body, Right, Title, Subtitle,Icon ,Content, Footer, FooterTab, Button, Text,Badge , List , ListItem} from 'native-base'
import Icon0 from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons'
import Icon1 from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome'
import CountDown from 'react-native-countdown-component';
import moment from 'moment';


class Consulter extends Component{


  state ={
    data:[]
  }
  fetchData= async()=>{
      const response = await fetch('http://192.168.1.4:3000/rendezvous/1');
      const rendezvous =await response.json();
      this.setState({data:rendezvous});
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      this.fetchData();
  }




  render() {
    const today = this.state.currentDate;
    const day = moment(today).format("dddd");
    const date = moment(today).format("MMMM D, YYYY");
      return (
        <Container>
               <Content >
                 <View style ={{ flex:1}}>
                   <FlatList
                     data={this.state.data}
                     keyExtractor={(item,index) => index.toString()}
                     renderItem={({item}) =>
                     {let dates=item.date;

                      <View style={{backgroundColor:'#e6e6e6',padding:10,margin:10}}>
                        <ListItem icon>
                          <Left>
                            <Button style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}>
                              <Icon0 active name="doctor" />
                            </Button>
                          </Left>
                          <Body>
                            <Text>Nom du Docteur : Dr. {item.nom}</Text>
                          </Body>
                        </ListItem>
                        <ListItem icon>
                          <Left>
                            <Button style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}>
                              <Icon1 active name="calendar" />
                            </Button>
                          </Left>
                          <Body>
                            <Text>Date du rendez-vous :</Text>

                            <Text> dates </Text>
                          </Body>
                        </ListItem>
                        <ListItem icon>
                          <Left>
                            <Button style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}>
                              <Icon1 active name="calendar"/>
                            </Button>
                          </Left>
                          <Body>
                            <CountDown
                              until= {item.date}
                              timetoShow={('H', 'M', 'S')}
                              onFinish={() => alert('finished')}
                              onPress={() => alert('hello')}
                              size={10}
                            />
                        </Body>
                      </ListItem>
                    </View>
                  }}
                />
              </View>
            </Content>
          </Container>
        );
      }
}
    export default Consulter;
    const styles =StyleSheet.create({
      container : {
        flex: 1,
      }
    })
```

Ps : there is no compilation errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use a return statement, like that:

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.data}
    keyExtractor={(item,index) => index.toString()}
    renderItem={({item}) =>
    {let dates=item.date;

    return( 
         <View style={{backgroundColor:'#e6e6e6',padding:10,margin:10}}>
             <ListItem icon>
               ...
          );
```

Answer (score 0):

`renderItem` expects you to return some `jsx` ... and you didn't

Try this:

```
  <FlatList
    data={this.state.data}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    renderItem={({ item: { date } }) => (<View>// the rest of your jsx</View>)}
  />
```